# Reactor Flux publish methods

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I need an explanation on these two methods from Reactor project

[docs-link](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#publish-int-)

- publish()

> Prepare a ConnectableFlux which shares this Flux sequence and dispatches values to subscribers in a backpressure-aware manner.

```
ConnectableFlux<T> publish()
```

And

- publish(int prefetch)

> Prepare a ConnectableFlux which shares this Flux sequence and dispatches values to subscribers in a backpressure-aware manner.

```
ConnectableFlux<T>  publish(int prefetch)
```

Marble diagrams are the same for both. What is `int prefetch` parameter for?

I run these examples and the results are the same

```
public static void publish() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux fl = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .publish()
            .autoConnect();
    fl.subscribe(printing);
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    fl.subscribe(printing);
}

public static void publishWithPrefetch() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux fl = Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
            .publish(2)
            .autoConnect();
    fl.subscribe(printing);
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    fl.subscribe(printing);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your documentation links are the same target.

The prefetch allows you to get more result at once, allowing some kind of buffering when managing the result.
Anyway, at end you will still have the same results; it's more an efficiency/performance question to use one or the other method.

Comment: yes missed the link its just above, so it has something to do with build in optimization right ?

Comment: Not the 'build' process, but the runtime execution one. You will see improvements when you will have lots of data to manage. I guess you won't with little scaled data.